# MS Access, in trigger, SetField to format(Now(),"Short Date") broken

Tags: ms-access

MS Office 365 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

I recently noticed that the definitions of set field commands in triggers I've written have changed without my doing.  I recently split the DB (frontend/backend), but am not sure if this is what caused this.  Here's what happened...

Before:

```
SetField
    Name last_mod_date
    Value =Format(Now(),"Short Date")
```

Now...

```
SetField
    Name last_mod_date
    Value =Format(Now()|"Short Date")
```

(That's not a typo, the "|" replaced the ",")

If all I do is click the "Before Change" (under "Table" tab, to see my triggers), and then "Save", I get a pop-up...

```
The 'SetField' macro action has an invalid value for the 'Value' argument."
```

(and it highlights the "Value" line) in the SetField block.

IOW, I made no changes, but it no longer likes what's there.
And I can understand that.  Where did the "|" come from?  I didn't put it there. Anyway, I replace it with a "," (common sense), click "Save" and get the same pop-up.

It would be interesting to know why my "," got replaced with "|".  But I'd much rather learn how to just fix this.  The Format(Now(),"Short Date") doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: My fix would be to use VBA. I don't use macros. If you don't want time part then why use Now(), just use: `Value = Date()`. Format() function actually returns a string, not a true date/time value. Date/time is really stored as a double number in date/time type field.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna love this.
I figured it out.  In order to be able to import a csv with a delimiter other than ",", I set the list delimiter (using... control panel -> Regional Language Settings -> List Delimiter) to (you guessed it) "|".  I just set it back and the problem is gone.

Why on Earth would the default list separator setting affect the content of a trigger definition deep inside an Access trigger is beyond me.  But there it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should never attempt to store date/time as text - which is what Format returns. So:

```
SetField
    Name last_mod_date
    Value = Now()
```

To store the date only:

```
SetField
    Name last_mod_date
    Value = Date()
```

Comment: Hi Gustav.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm still pretty much a Windows/VBA novice when it comes to coding, so I'm all ears :-) .  The column definition for the target is a "Date/Time" and the format is "Short Date".  So I was thinking I had to format the value before stuffing into the column.  Maybe not ?

Comment: A date value carries no format. The format is for display only.